# Error while publishing asp.net website in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, browser, iis-7, web, directory-listing

I am trying to publish my asp.net website on LAN ans i have IIS7 installed on my system i copied all files in "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Elearn\"
and converted it into Application but when i try to access it in browser it gives this error.
[image]

Please help me to rectify and run my site. Thanks

i get Error when i tried to access my site via Directory Listing .[image]

Comment: Can you please give us more details about the error you are getting? Did you check Application Pool?

Comment: well the only error i am getting is clearly stated in the picture i have attached , i know nothing more than that.
:(

Comment: There is no picture or attachment in your post. At least I don't see it there.

Comment: Well have a look:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/SzEQn.png

Comment: and this one:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/vVoJp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the landing page for your site called? If it's not default.aspx, or similar, you will need to add it as a default document in IIS.

Also, double check the permissions on that directory and make sure your app pool user has the appropriate access to it, and that it inherits down.

Comment: well my default page is index.aspx and i made it starting page in Visual Studio while developing , do i have to Set my starting page again in IIS7 somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, IIS7 doesn't not have that as a start page by default. To add it, click on your site in IIS7, and double click Default Document in the middle column. Click add in the right, and enter index.aspx

Comment: well made my directory listing enabled so that i can access any page , still i am getting error. i am attaching error page .Plz have a look

Comment: Change the App Pool on your site to one of the ASP.NET v4.0 app pools. If you look at the bottom of your new error, is states that it's trying to render it in framework 2.0.

Comment: BTW, if you don't know how: Click on your site in IIS, click on Basic Settings in the right column, Click Select at the top of the popup and then choose ASP.NET v4.0 or ASP.NET v4.0 Classic

Comment: Hey Buddy Thanks , Yes it was the Framework Version that was troubling me.
Thanks a lot 
:)